# What determines the order of attacks in Terra Battle?

Tags: terra-battle

Is there any way to know which of my attacks will go first/second/third?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is entirely possible to predict the order of the attacks. Here's how it works:

1. pincers that are made horizontally will always activate before vertical ones
2. if there are same types, pincers will activate in order from left to right, bottom to top
3. if the character you use to move that turn participates as one of the main attackers, that pincer will always activate first

Source: Taken from [this helpful post](http://puzzleanddragonsforum.com/showthread.php?tid=56271&pid=663803#pid663803) on the P&D forums.